# Adding left right button in matplotlib scrollbar

Tags: python, matplotlib

Recently, I am focusing on producing a time series graph. I read all the csv data to python by using pandas,which the time will be the index.

scrollbar is added as aid for presentation. I import Slider from matplotlib.widgets to produce it. And All looks fine.

However, I want to improve it. The graph now I produce is not bad. If I want to go into the datapoint I can just click the Slider bar.

However, is it possible to add a button to control the slider bar.
What I mean is that can I add a right button. Once I click this right button, the whole graph will move right 5 datapoint( or 5 minutes as it is a time series model)
And can I make a 'left' button too?
Therefore, if I will go fast I can direct click the Slider bar. Then, If i wanna present it slow, I can just click the button?

Actually, I have read some information about 'button library'. However, I don't know how to use it to update the Slider.

Here is my code

```
df_BA = cs_66667_BS[['BidPrice','AskPrice']]
title_name = 'cs_66667_BS'

ax = df_BA.plot(title= title_name, fontsize= 10, figsize=(20, 10))
ax.set_xlabel('Date', fontsize= 15)
ax.set_ylabel('Price', fontsize= 15)
plt.subplots_adjust(left= 0.04, bottom= 0.25, right= 0.99, top= 0.95, wspace= 0, hspace= 0.1 )

x= df_BA.index.to_pydatetime()
x_min_index = 0
x_max_index = 1

x_min = x[0]
x_max = x[-1] - datetime.timedelta(minutes=4)
y_min = df_BA.BidPrice.min()
y_max = df_BA.AskPrice.max()

# timedelta
x_dt = datetime.timedelta(minutes=5)
axcolor = 'lightgoldenrodyellow'
axpos = plt.axes([0.05, 0.1, 0.9, 0.05], axisbg=axcolor)
slider_max = len(x) - x_max_index - 1

# Slider(axes, name, min, max)
spos = Slider(axpos, 'Pos', matplotlib.dates.date2num(x_min), matplotlib.dates.date2num(x_max))
# pretty date names
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()

def update(val):
    pos = spos.val
    xmin_time = matplotlib.dates.num2date(pos)
    xmax_time = matplotlib.dates.num2date(pos) + x_dt
    xmin_time = pos
    ax.axis([xmin_time, xmax_time, y_min, y_max])
    ########################################################
    fig.canvas.draw_idle()

spos.on_changed(update)

plt.show()
```

Comment: What you mean is a **button**, not a bottom.

Comment: Oh yes,  Thank you

Comment: Also see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38150315/discrete-sliders-for-multiple-sliders-python).

Answer (score 2):

You can easily add a `matplotlib.widgets.Button` to the plot, in the same way you added a `matplotlib.widgets.Slider`.
You can then connect the button to a function `forward()` or `backward()` which will set the Slider to a new position.

Here is a complete working example which is hopefully close enough to your's (I did change some stuff though)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider, Button
import datetime
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

rng = pd.date_range(datetime.datetime.now(), periods=340, freq='T')

data = {'BidPrice': np.random.random(340)*np.sin(np.arange(340)/30.),
        'AskPrice': np.random.random(340)*np.sin(np.arange(340)/30.-2) }
df_BA = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['BidPrice','AskPrice'], index=rng)

ax = df_BA.plot(title= "Title", fontsize= 10, figsize=(10, 8))
ax.set_xlabel('Date', fontsize= 15)
ax.set_ylabel('Price', fontsize= 15)
plt.subplots_adjust(left= 0.04, bottom= 0.25, right= 0.99, top= 0.95, wspace= 0, hspace= 0.1 )

x= df_BA.index.to_pydatetime()

x_min = x[0]
x_max = x[0] + datetime.timedelta(minutes=20)
y_min = df_BA.BidPrice.min()
y_max = df_BA.AskPrice.max()
ax.set_xlim([x_min, x_max])
ax.set_ylim([y_min, y_max])

x_dt = datetime.timedelta(minutes=10)

axpos = plt.axes([0.2, 0.1, 0.58, 0.03], axisbg='w')
axpos1 = plt.axes([0.05, 0.1, 0.05, 0.03], axisbg='w')
axpos2 = plt.axes([0.93, 0.1, 0.05, 0.03], axisbg='w')

# Slider(axes, name, min, max)
spos = Slider(axpos, 'Pos', matplotlib.dates.date2num(x_min), matplotlib.dates.date2num(x[-1]))
spos.set_val(matplotlib.dates.date2num(x[0]))

button1 = Button(axpos1, '<', color='w', hovercolor='b')
button2 = Button(axpos2, '>', color='w', hovercolor='b')


def update(val):
    pos = spos.val
    xmin_time = matplotlib.dates.num2date(pos)
    xmax_time = matplotlib.dates.num2date(pos) + x_dt
    ax.set_xlim([xmin_time, xmax_time ])
    plt.gcf().canvas.draw_idle()

def forward(vl):
    pos = spos.val
    spos.set_val(matplotlib.dates.date2num( matplotlib.dates.num2date(pos) + datetime.timedelta(minutes=5) ))
def backward(vl):
    pos = spos.val
    spos.set_val(matplotlib.dates.date2num( matplotlib.dates.num2date(pos) - datetime.timedelta(minutes=5) ))

spos.on_changed(update)
button1.on_clicked(backward)
button2.on_clicked(forward)

plt.show()
```