# How to format the slider value to datetime pattern in the matplotlib figure?

Tags: python, matplotlib

[The figure picture!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TJgcf.png)
Just like the picture, how can i format the number to datetime pattern. For example format 1472860800.0 to 2016-09-03.It can't use the datetime module to format directly. The key point is that it should be formatted in the matplotlib firgure. It is a slider value, and i have read the matplotlib docs ,but i haven't found the sloution.Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Use [datetime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#module-datetime) module

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datetime.fromtimestamp(1472860800).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
'2016-09-03'
```

Comment: I kown the datetime module. The key point is that it should be formatted in the matplotlib firgure. It is slider value, and i have read the matplotlib docs ,but i haven't found the sloution.

Comment: Look on [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13656387/can-i-make-matplotlib-sliders-more-discrete), I think it is going to be helpful