# How to reduce idle time when using Matplotlib interactive buttons

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, matplotlib-widget

I suspect I am using the interactive features of `matplotlib`somehow in the wrong way, because I have to wait several seconds between one plot and the next when using the following code and structures.

My data base is a `pandas` `DataFrame` of around (3800 x 56) `float`, with a 3-D hyerachical index.

```
df = mydf.set_index(['l1','l2','l3'])
```

I then go on creating the `matplotlib` `figure` and `axes`

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
up_button_ax  = fig.add_axes([0.25, 0.15, 0.1, 0.03], facecolor='grey')
up_button= Button(up_button_ax, 'pga_up')
dn_button_ax  = fig.add_axes([0.25, 0.1, 0.1, 0.03], facecolor='grey')
dn_button= Button(dn_button_ax, 'pga_dn')
```

I struggled with the `Slider` as I wanted it to take only integers, so I finally went for two buttons and had to use a small object to keep their state.

(not directly my question, but any suggestion whether there are other interactive elements which would avoid creation of this object would be welcome)

```
class Index(object):
    ind = 0

    def next(self):
        self.ind += 1

    def prev(self):
        self.ind -= 1

callback = Index()

def up_button_on_clicked(mouse_event):
    callback.next()
    plot_data(callback.ind)
    print('up i: {}'.format(callback.ind))
up_button.on_clicked(up_button_on_clicked)

def dn_button_on_clicked(mouse_event):
    callback.prev()
    plot_data(callback.ind)
    print('dn i: {}'.format(callback.ind))
dn_button.on_clicked(dn_button_on_clicked)

def plot_data(i):        
    dfnow = df.xs(df.index.levels[0][i]) #slice by CMOD TUNE
    ax.clear()
    for c_pga in dfnow.index.levels[0]:
        if not(dfnow.xs(c_pga).empty):
            ax.plot(dfnow.xs(c_pga)['L1 (dBm)'],marker = 'o',markersize=1,label=c_pga)
    ax.set_title('CMOD TUNE: {}'.format(df.index.levels[0][i]))
```

Upon execution, every time I click the button, I see the printout immediately, but have to wait quite a long time to have the data finally plotted.

If, on the other hand, I call `plot_data(i)` from the shell, plotting is immediate.
I am therefore assuming that I am not calling the right drawing functions, but have no clue here.

**EDIT**

Inspired by a second read of Joe_Kington's [reply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13656387/can-i-make-matplotlib-sliders-more-discrete) on discrete `Slider` (thanks to Tom for this), I thought of adding this simple line to my `plot_data(i)` function:

```
fig.canvas.draw()
```

Drawing is now immediate. I would still be grateful if somebody would point me to the reasons why this is needed.

Comment: Regarding your secondary question: You can make a discrete slider to take only integers. See the excellent answer by @JoeKington here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13656387/can-i-make-matplotlib-sliders-more-discrete

Comment: Thanks @tom -- I had tried the first line suggested, i.e. using a proper `fmt` specification, but had the impression that this was only *displaying* the integer steps, while internally keeping a "continuous" sweep. I decided this would have caused problems as I'm using the slider to index a discrete set of rows in my `df`.
I firstly stumbled on what I think would have been the easiest solution of all: specify a step interval.
However, the `valstep` keyword is not recognized by my version.
https://matplotlib.org/api/widgets_api.html?highlight=slider#matplotlib.widgets.Slider

Comment: Yep, I meant the later part of the answer where he subclasses Slider

Comment: Yes, I was up for a quick one yesterday :)
I was trying to work around the use of classes, mainly because I'm ignorant.